# Reading files from a VMware Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I've an old VMware virtual machine (.VMDK).
It has been installed as Windows XP. It runs but I forgot the Windows password to login.

Is it possible to use the VM as a virtual drive and just READ OUT THE FILES stored into it as it was a normal HD? 
I don't need to execute the VM, only to recover some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mount a vmdk file in Windows or Linux, read [HERE](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/VMwareDiskMount.pdf). Becuase it is password protected C drive I would mount it in Linux and just copy what I needed since Linux will read the filesystem without the need for a password where windows is likely not going to allow you to read without the password.